# ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/ Can't login to django admin after creating a super user with a custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I'am trying to logging into the django admin panel with a superuser I have successfully created but evrytimes it gives me the ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/ saying that settings.DATABASES is improperly configured but I have check everything and nothing seems wrong the thing is that I'am also using multiple database with postgresql so the supersuer created is my user_account app, only this is the code of : the models.py of my user_account app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

# Create your models here.
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def email_validator(self,email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            raise ValueError(_("please enter a valid email address"))
        
    def create_user(self, email, name, phone_number, password=None):
        if email:
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
            self.email_validator(email)
        else:
            raise ValueError(_("an email address is required"))
        if not name:
            raise ValueError(_("first name is required"))
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError(_("phone number is required"))
        
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name, phone_number=phone_number)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_member(self, email, name, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, phone_number,password) 
        user.is_member = True 
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = False

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, name, phone_number, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, phone_number, password) 
        user.is_member = True 
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True 

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager() 

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['name', 'phone_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

and this is my router.py file

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {"user_account", "admin", "contenttypes", "sessions", "auth",}  

    
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'users'
        return None
    
    
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'users'
        return None
    
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if(
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or 
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None 
    
    
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'users'
        return None
```

from my settings.py

```
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'user_account',
    'CarListingService',
    'CarBookingService',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'CarRentalProject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'CarRentalProject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {},
    "users": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "carrental_users",
        "USER": 'postgres',
        "PASSWORD": "admin@#2024",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432"
    },
    "Carlisting": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "carrental_carlisting",
        "USER": "postgres", 
        "PASSWORD": "admin@#2024",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432"
    },
    "Carbooking":{
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "carrental_carbookings",
        "USER": "postgres", 
        "PASSWORD": "admin@#2024",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432"
    }
}

DATABASES_ROUTERS = ["user_account.router.AuthRouter"]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', 
    ],

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
    
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken', ) 
}



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL="user_account.UserAccount"
```

and the urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('api/token/Refresh', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
    path('api/token/Verify', TokenVerifyView.as_view()), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

this is the error I'am having

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/
Exception Value: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I have also check the docs but nothing seems to help
please I need your help please.

Comment: Keep your _secret key_ in secret.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `route_app_labels` variable provided in `AuthRouter` includes references to `rest_framework` and `rest_framework_simplejwt` due to the usage of `rest_framework` authentication classes.

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {"user_account", "admin", "contenttypes", "sessions", "auth", "rest_framework", "rest_framework_simplejwt"}  


    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'users'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'users'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if(
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or 
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None 

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'users'
        return None
```

Try this one.

Comment: Thanks but am still facing the same problem